# Using 言う and ても to mean "even if you say"

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I was trying to say something similar to "even if you tell me to not look, I will look", so my initial guess was something along those lines:

「見ないで」と言っても見る。

I was under the impression that Xて-form + も would yield something like "even if you x, ..."

However searching for 言っても on weblio. So the question is, would 言っても have the meaning "even if you say X, ...", if not what would would be the idiomatic way to say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「見ないで」と言っても見る。

This looks already perfect to me, and it does mean "Even if you tell me not to look, ...". The subject of each verb can be safely inferred as long as you say this in the right context.